# How to apply IntersectionObserver to v-for directive in Composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, intersection-observer

I can use an `IntersectionObserver` to lazy-load images like so:

```
<template>
  <div id="gallery" class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-card">
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/1.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/ph.png" data-src="../../images/2.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/ph.png" data-src="../../images/3.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/ph.png" data-src="../../images/4.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/ph.png" data-src="../../images/5.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="../../images/ph.png" data-src="../../images/6.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import {onMounted} from "vue";

onMounted(() => {
    let config = {
        rootMargin: '0px 0px 50px 0px',
        threshold: 0
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, self) {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if(entry.isIntersecting) {
                const img = entry.target
                img.src = img.dataset.src
                self.unobserve(img);
            }
        });
    }, config);

    const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll('[data-src]');
    lazyImages.forEach(img => {
        observer.observe(img);
    });
})

</script>
```

but when I try to observe elements, generated with the `v-for` directive, the observer isn't able to read the rendered elements. I assume that the observer runs before the elements are rendered.

How do I apply the `IntersectionObserver` to elements generated in the `v-for` directive like:

```
<template>
  <div id="gallery" class="gallery">
    <div v-for="row in imageTable" class="gallery-card">
      <a href="#gallery-view"><img :src="'../../images/ph.png'" :data-src="'/storage' + row['path']"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you tried referencing the items created with v-for using refs? It should create an array within the `$refs` reference, and I imagine that the array would be available at mount-time.

Comment: Or even better, you can make f.e. LazyLoadImage component. No need to handle it from outside..

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've done that but where I fail is applying the `isIntersecting` condition to the ref. What ref property shows if the viewport is intersecting the referenced element?